# Check whether given a pair of arrays are permutation of each other

Tags: c++, algorithm, combinatorics

Does this implementation guarantee execution of \$O(n)\$ time?  What is the additional space utilization for this implementation by excluding the original array size? Is it \$O(1)\$?

```
#include<iostream>
#include<set>
#include<algorithm>


bool ArraysPermute(int  array1[],int size1, int  array2[], int size2)
{       
       if( size1  != size2)           
           return false;
       else
       {        
           std::set<int> first_set(array1, array1+size1);
           std::set<int> second_set(array2, array2+size2);

           std::pair<std::set<int>::iterator,std::set<int>::iterator> myPair=std::mismatch(first_set.begin(),first_set.end(),second_set.begin());

           if( *myPair.first != *myPair.second)

                return false;
            else
                return true;
       }
}


int main()
{     
    int array1[] ={1,2,3,5};
    int array2[]={1,2,4,3};

    if(ArraysPermute(array1,sizeof(array1)/sizeof(int), array2, sizeof(array2)/sizeof(int)))
        std::cout<< " Arrays are permutation of each other\n"; 
    else
        std::cout<< " Arrays are not permutation of each other\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: On a side note, there is always [`std::is_permutation`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/is_permutation) in the standard library since C++11 :)

Comment: @Morwenn: the cpp reference hints that `std::is_permutation` has a complexity worst case of *O(n2)*. Unless the template is special cased for `int`, it could be much slower.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Complexity

You suggest that the performance is \$O(n)\$, but it is not. It is \$O(n \log{n})\$ because [the `set` constructor](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/set/set/set/) is a binary-tree building algorithm that has an additional log(n) operations for each value.

### Style

While your code is all neat, and well laid out, the variable names are good, etc., there are two issues I see with unnecessary else-condiditions on if-statements, and un-braced 1-liners. Additionally, white-space around punctuation and operators is useful for readability. This code:

> ```
>   if( size1  != size2)           
>        return false;
>    else
>    {        
>        std::set<int> first_set(array1, array1+size1);
>        std::set<int> second_set(array2, array2+size2);
>
>        std::pair<std::set<int>::iterator,std::set<int>::iterator> myPair=std::mismatch(first_set.begin(),first_set.end(),second_set.begin());
>
>        if( *myPair.first != *myPair.second)
>
>             return false;
>         else
>             return true;
>    }
> ```

should be written:

```
if( size1 != size2)
{
    return false;
}
std::set<int> first_set(array1, array1 + size1);
std::set<int> second_set(array2, array2 + size2);

std::pair<std::set<int>::iterator, std::set<int>::iterator> myPair   
   = std::mismatch(first_set.begin(), first_set.end(), second_set.begin());

return *myPair.first == *myPair.second;
```

### Bugs

The `set` construct keeps just a single entry for all instances of a given value. Thus, for example, given the input `[1,2,3,4,4,4,4]` it will have just 4 entries.

This leads to bugs in your code when there are duplicates. For example, your code will identify the following two input arrays as being permutations of each other:

```
[1,2,3,4,5,5,5]
[1,1,1,2,3,4,5]
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. To resolve the bug, I may need to use std::vector in place of std::set and sort it before checking the std::mismatch, I will correct it.

Comment: Most of the std::sort implementations are in n(logn), so again second version  should ends up in O(nlogn) performance

Comment: Reference from the link you mentioned in your answer.    " range constructor :     Constructs a container with as many elements as the range [first,last), with each element emplace-constructed from its corresponding element in that range."  It is obvious running an operation is O(nlogn) with std:;set, but I think construction is O(n) for a range based constructor of std::set

Comment: @Steephen: Rather than `std::set` you could you use `std::map` and count the number of each elements. But this is still `O(nlog(n))`. You could try `std::unordered_map` rather than map to improve the performance. Then you can probably get `O(n)`.

Comment: @LokiAstari Doesn't range based construction of std::set running in O(n)?

Comment: @Steephen - if you read the documentation again, you will see it says (emphasis mine): *For all other cases, linear in the distance between the iterators **if the elements are already sorted according to the same criterion**. For **unsorted sequences**, linearithmic **(N*logN)** in that distance ...*

Comment: @Steephen: Sure if your range is already sorted. But I don't see that as a stipulation about your input arrays. Otherwise it is `O(n.log(n))`

Answer (score 2):

This code runs in \$O(n \log{n})\$ time because a C++ set is a Red-Black tree, and insertions/deletions/finds run in \$O(\log{n})\$ time. In addition, since you are not using a multiset, your code is not actually correct for arrays with duplicate elements.

In order to resolve this, a simple solution is to use an `std::unordered_map` (which is a hash table with \$O(1)\$ operations) with the element as the key and the number of occurrences as the value. Construct a map for the 1st and 2nd arrays, and then iterate over the keys (or the array, complexity will be the same) and verify that the values are the same in both maps.

Comment: construction of first_set itself will take O(n) complexity since it is using a range based constructor of std::set.  And none of the listed operations of std::set , listed in your answer  are not using also here. So how did you calculate its order is O(nlogn)?

Comment: Set construction takes O(nlogn) for unsorted arrays. See http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/set/set/set/. The construction process could be thought of us a series of n insertions, even if it's not implemented that way. I mostly added the operation information for completeness's sake.

Answer (score 1):

### Algorithm and Complexity

As reported in other answers, your program most likely executes in \$O(n.log(n))\$ time and uses \$O(n)\$ extra space, probably substantially more than the original space used by the arrays, and may report erroneous results because of a bad choice of class.

### Better algorithm

Forget using anything this sophisticated, this problem can be solved in \$O(n)\$ time with astute brute force, while still using \$O(n)\$ extra space:

- make temporary copies of array1 and array2
- sort both temporary arrays
- compare them -> if equal, result is true, otherwise false.
- free the temporary arrays.

You may think the complexity to be \$O(n.log(n))\$, and it may be so if you use the standard sort method, but keep in mind these arrays are a special case that can be sorted in \$O(n)\$ time using [Radix sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_sort)

I am not familiar enough with C++ to tell if you will need to implement radix sort yourself or if the *standard* array sort will perform correctly.

### Style

- indentation is inconsistent;
- use white space more systematically and consistently;
- keep line length under control: a limit of 79 characters is advisable;
- the number of elements in the arrays should be computed in a safer way with `sizeof(array1) / sizeof(array1[0])` instead of `sizeof(array1)/sizeof(int)`

Comment: How do you propose to sort an array in O(_n_) time?

Comment: @200_success: HaHa! look up radix sort: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_sort

Comment: That's an iffy claim, as the problem does not state a limit on the size of the elements.

Comment: The elements are `int`.  Running `sizeof(int)` passes of distribution sort over 256 buckets will sort the array in *O(n)* time

Comment: @chqrlie Could you please explain why sizeof(array1) / sizeof(array1[0]) is safer than sizeof(array1)/sizeof(int) ?

Comment: @Steephen: call this defensive programming.  If you or the next programmer/maintainer of this piece of code later change the type of `array1` and `array2` to a type with a different size (`short` or `long` for example) or if you cut and paste the code to a different function where these types differ, forgetting to update the `sizeof(int)` will cause spurious bugs where using an expression independent of the type of `array1` will not.

Comment: If the question was tagged [tag:performance], too, I'd suggest to establish "the first digit histogram of the other array" after starting to sort one. If histograms don't match, the arrays aren't permutations. One could throw in any cheap position-independent summary information, parity (ExOr) coming to mind.

Comment: @greybeard: That's a good point, but the complexity of this test is *O(n)* so it is still relatively expensive for a negative test compared to the complete test that provides a definitive answer.

Comment: `relatively expensive` while establishing *cheap position-independent summary information* such as parity or min&max (useful in sizing histogram buffers) doesn't need additional "bulk memory access", comparing histograms doesn't need any additional "input traversal" - it *does* add "parallel traversal" of "both" histograms (each of which, on the other hand, better fit in 1st level cache, anyway).

Comment: @greybeard: I agree. As a matter of fact, the same cheap scan can be used for both a faster negative test in many cases and a fast positive test if both arrays happen to have the same contents. Additional space requirements and cache handling for large sizes do make the full test much slower.