# Is_permutation() on sequence containers in O(n) complexity - follow-up

Tags: c++, algorithm, combinatorics, stl, c++14

This question is a continuation of my previous question:

[Check is_permutation on a pair of same sized arrays](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/84974/check-is-permutation-on-a-pair-of-same-sized-arrays).

I improved the implementation to generalize for all sequence containers. Please let me know how I can improve this implementation again.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<algorithm>
#include<unordered_map>
#include<array>
#include<list>

template < typename T1 >
std::unordered_map< int, int > count_frequency( T1 first, T1 last )
{
    std::unordered_map< int, int > temp_unordered_map;
    auto temp_unordered_map_end = std::end( temp_unordered_map );
    while( first != last )
    {
        auto it_temp_unordered_map = temp_unordered_map.find( *first );
        if( it_temp_unordered_map == temp_unordered_map_end )
        {
            temp_unordered_map.emplace( *first, 1 );                       
        }
        else
        {
            ++( it_temp_unordered_map->second );
        }
        ++first;
    }
    return temp_unordered_map;
}

template < typename T1, typename T2 >
bool is_permutation( const T1 first1, const T1 last1, const T2 first2, const T2 last2 )
{   
    if( std::distance( first1, last1 ) != std::distance( first2, last2 ) )
    {
        return false;  
    }
    std::unordered_map< int, int > first_map = count_frequency( first1, last1 );        
    std::unordered_map< int, int > second_map = count_frequency( first2, last2 );

    std::pair<std::unordered_map< int, int >::iterator,std::unordered_map< int, int >::iterator > myPair=
        std::mismatch( std::begin( first_map ), std::end( first_map ), std::begin( second_map ), 
        []( std::pair< const int, int >& seed1, std::pair< const int, int > & seed2) 
        { return seed1.second == seed2.second; }
        );

    return  myPair.first == first_map.end() && myPair.second == second_map.end(); 
}

int main()
{     
    const std::array< int, 5> array1 { { 1, 3, 2, 4, 5 } };
    const std::array<int,4> array2 { { 1, 2, 4, 3 } };

    if( ::is_permutation( std::begin( array1 ), std::end( array1 ), std::begin( array2 ), std::end( array2 ) ) )
    {
        std::cout<< " Elements are permutation of each other\n"; 
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout<< " Elements are not permutation of each other\n";
    }

    const std::vector< int > vec1 { { 1, 3, 2, 4 } };
    const std::vector< int > vec2 { { 1, 2, 4, 3 } };

    if( ::is_permutation( std::begin( vec1 ), std::end( vec1 ), std::begin( vec2 ), std::end( vec2 ) ) )
    {
        std::cout<< " Elements are permutation of each other\n"; 
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout<< " Elements are not permutation of each other\n";
    }

    const std::list< int > list1 { { 1, 3, 2, 4 } };
    const std::list< int > list2 { { 1, 2, 4, 3 } };

    if( ::is_permutation( std::begin( list1 ), std::end( list1 ), std::begin( list2 ), std::end( list2 ) ) )
    {
        std::cout<< " Elements are permutation of each other\n"; 
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout<< " Elements are not permutation of each other\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I like to add my grain of salt, so here it is:

- While `const` is interesting for pointer or references parameter, it tends to be less useful otherwise. I would use it only when it changes something for the user. Typically, when you pass parameters by copy (which is what is done for iterators), it is useless to `const`-qualify them, especially since you actually pass them by copy again to another function that takes non-`const` iterators and modifies them. I wouldn't even be surprised if it hindered performance and/or compiler optimizations at some point.
- While a double pair of braces is necessary to initialize an `std::array` without getting a warning with Clang, I really consider it to be syntactic noise and I avoid it as much as possible. It isn't needed for `std::list` and `std::vector`, so I would use a simple pair of braces which in my opinion better conveys what you are doing (well, it's eventually subjective).
- I agree with @rolfl about the redundant range-size equality check in `is_permutation`. Moreover, `std::distance` is \$O(n)\$ for most iterator types, so you are adding an actual runtime cost here.

  However, `std::distance` is \$O(1)\$ for random-access iterators, range size checking may indeed be faster for those. Therefore, you could make two versions of `is_permutation`: one that takes random-access iterators and one that only takes regular input iterators. Add a layer of tag dispatching and let the compiler pick the most well-suited function for you:

  ```
  template < typename T1, typename T2 >
  bool is_permutation_impl( const T1 first1, const T1 last1, const T2 first2, const T2 last2, std::input_iterator_tag )
  {
      return count_frequency( first1, last1 ) == count_frequency( first2, last2 );
  }

  template < typename T1, typename T2 >
  bool is_permutation_impl( const T1 first1, const T1 last1, const T2 first2, const T2 last2, std::random_access_iterator_tag )
  {
      if( std::distance( first1, last1 ) != std::distance( first2, last2 ) )
      {
          return false;  
      }
      return count_frequency( first1, last1 ) == count_frequency( first2, last2 );
  }

  template < typename T1, typename T2 >
  bool is_permutation( const T1 first1, const T1 last1, const T2 first2, const T2 last2 )
  {
      return is_permutation_impl(
          first1, last1,
          first2, last2,
          std::iterator_traits<T1>::iterator_category{}
      );
  }
  ```

  Note that my tag dispatching is not fully correct because it only checks whether the first range is a random-access range, while it should check whether both ranges are. You can implement the correct behaviour with a little bit more template stuff, but it will be left as an exercise to the reader (mostly be cause I am not motivated enough to do it myself right now).

Answer (score 3):

I would initially agree that the complexity of your solution is O(n), though, there are extreme cases where the performance of your `count_frequency` could be greater - `unordered_map.emplace()` is 'average case constant time, worst case linear', I don't believe a worst-case situation would happen for you.

Note that you have a very complicated equality-check comparing your two frequency-maps.... you have:

> ```
> if( std::distance( first1, last1 ) != std::distance( first2, last2 ) )
> {
>     return false;  
> }
> std::unordered_map< int, int > first_map = count_frequency( first1, last1 );        
> std::unordered_map< int, int > second_map = count_frequency( first2, last2 );
>
> std::pair<std::unordered_map< int, int >::iterator,std::unordered_map< int, int >::iterator > myPair=
>     std::mismatch( std::begin( first_map ), std::end( first_map ), std::begin( second_map ), 
>     []( std::pair< const int, int >& seed1, std::pair< const int, int > & seed2) 
>     { return seed1.second == seed2.second; }
>     );
>
> return  myPair.first == first_map.end() && myPair.second == second_map.end();
> ```

as far as I can tell, the size-check is redundant, and the rest can be simply:

```
template < typename T1, typename T2 >
bool is_permutation( const T1 first1, const T1 last1, const T2 first2, const T2 last2 )
{   
    return count_frequency( first1, last1 ) == count_frequency( first2, last2 );
}
```

I put [your code in this ideone](http://ideone.com/Z7syuE), and the replacement code in [this ideone here](http://ideone.com/6qj7sk).